# Launch InstallShield 7 EXE from WIX Burn bootstrapper

Tags: wix, installshield, burn

I have the following WIX Burn bootstrapper code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
<Bundle Name="Test" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Test" UpgradeCode="cc44096e-23a6-48ab-a1f1-c75648358049">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
        <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication SuppressOptionsUI="yes" LicenseUrl="" LogoFile="Logo.bmp"/>
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <Variable Name="InstallParameter" bal:Overridable="yes" Type="string" Value="" />

    <Chain>
        <ExePackage Name="VS2012_Redist_x86_exe" SourceFile="..\vcredist_x86_2012.exe" DetectCondition="ExeDetectedVariable" Permanent="yes" InstallCommand='/Q' />
        <ExePackage Name="Pack" SourceFile="..\Install.exe" DetectCondition="ExeDetectedVariable" Permanent="no" InstallCommand='[InstallParameter]' />
    </Chain>
</Bundle>
</Wix>
```

So, it first launches the Visual Studio 2012 redistributable and then the Install.exe.
Install.exe is a setup build with InstallShield 7 (not an MSI based one).
The WIX code compiles fine using WIX 3.7. When running the installer, the VS redistributable installs fine, but the Install.exe starts and when trying to copy the first file it gives me:

```
---------------------------
Component transfer error
---------------------------
Component:  Component1.
File Group: 
File:       
Error:      Catastrophic failure
```

Any idea how I can launch this InstallShield based installer from the WIX Burn bootstrapper?

EDIT: Turns out the problem was with the Name="Pack" attribute in the second ExePackage. Simply removing that attribute made the installer work. I find it very strange that that attribute can have such side-effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with the Name="Pack" attribute in the second ExePackage. Simply removing that attribute made the installer work. I find it very strange that that attribute can have such side-effect.